# MS Access SQL sub Query using outer query result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to run a sub query based on the result of an outer query.  The issue that I am having is that instead of using the outer query, I get a prompt for a value from the subquery.

```
SELECT Facilities.CustomerName, Facilities.FacilityName,
   Facilities.AnnualPlan, Facilities.AppCo1, 
   (SELECT YeildDB.CornYield
    FROM YeildDB
    WHERE Facilites.AppCo1 = YeildDB.FIPS) AS Expr1
FROM Facilities
```

The goal is that the sub query should use the value from `Facilities.AppCo1` to match with the value in `YeildDB.FIPS` and then return the corresponding value in `YeildDB.CornYeild`.

Currently I get a prompt asking for the `YeildDB.FIPS` value instead of the sub query using the outer query value.

Comment: Then Access is unable to locate an attribute named 'FIPS' in that table 'YeilDB''.  Check the table definition.  It's unlikely, but perhaps it could help writing `WHERE YeildDB.FIPS = Facilites.AppCo1` instead, and add that lacking third 'i' in 'Facilites'.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work.  But you can also express this using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Facilities.CustomerName, Facilities.FacilityName,
       Facilities.AnnualPlan, Facilities.AppCo1, 
       YeildDB.CornYield
FROM Facilities LEFT JOIN
     YeildDB
     ON Facilties.AppCo1 = YeildDB.FIPS;
```

I noticed that you misspelled `Facilities` -- and that is probably why your version doesn't work.  This is one reason to use table aliases:

```
SELECT f.CustomerName, f.FacilityName,
       f.AnnualPlan, f.AppCo1, 
       y.CornYield
FROM Facilities as f LEFT JOIN
     YeildDB as y
     ON f.AppCo1 = y.FIPS;
```

Comment: That works!  Thank you so much...I must have looked at that for an hour and missed the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query may be returning multiple values, hence the prompt asking you to specify which one you want.  You can fix this (or at least hide this issue) by specifying top 1:

```
SELECT Facilities.CustomerName, Facilities.FacilityName,
   Facilities.AnnualPlan, Facilities.AppCo1, 
   (SELECT TOP 1 YeildDB.CornYield
    FROM YeildDB
    WHERE Facilites.AppCo1 = YeildDB.FIPS) AS Expr1
FROM Facilities
```